# Is this a Polygon?

Tags: linear-algebra

According to the definition of Polygon, If a Poly-line's first and last points are connected  then it is called Polygon. See the image below. I have P1, .... P5 Polyline. If I draw a line from P5 to P1 then it will be called polygon or not? I am confused here.

[image]

Comment: Being confused is perfectly reasonable here!  Part of the problem is that there are *several* different definitions of polygon; to answer the question of whether your shape is a polygon or not, you'll have to be much more precise in the definition you're using.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, I am talking about this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon

Comment: Perhaps this would be relevant : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digon

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, It's mean the above shape can be called a polygon?

Comment: @user960567 : It means that some people would call that a polygon. Personally I don't think it's important to make a distinction, but if for you it is then some people agree that it can be considered a polygon. I have no idea if it's a good idea or not to do so, but I usually refer to polygons as non-degenerate ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think conventionally you would expect the area of a polygon to be non-zero.

Generally your lecturer/teacher should specify in lectures the exact definition of things, and you should use that to answer his/her questions.
If you find loopholes you should ask them about it.

According to the link for Wikipedia you supplied:

> In geometry a polygon is a flat shape consisting of straight lines
>   that are joined to form a closed chain or circuit.

Digging a little deeper you can find this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_polygonal_chain:

> In some cases it is important to draw a distinction between a
>   polygonal area and a polygonal chain.